# Command "GET /users" Gitlab api return 401 error

Tags: api, gitlab, http-status-code-401

I've created a Personal Access Token on my gitlab account with read_user scopes

[image: token]

I use this command :

```html
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users
```

And I get this return

```
{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}
```

Why ?

The read user scope should give me the necessary permissions to access / users On Gitlab it is written :

> Grants read-only access to the authenticated user's profile through
>   the /user API endpoint, which includes username, public email, and
>   full name. Also grants access to read-only API endpoints under /users.

Comment: Tried your code and worked fine. Are you using literal `<` and `>` in your key?

Comment: Yeah I use < and >
I try without those symbols and I works thanks :)
Now that seem be a stupid question but I couldn't find any example request ;/

Comment: It's okay. Good on you for your perseverance!